# Website supporting for mobile phone in php

Tags: php

I want to make a website which should open in  mobile perfectly. I went through more search and i got WML language based website. Is this not possible to make any website in concerns of design with mobile.Can WML run on php server as well ?

Need advice how to make a website for mobile application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of mobile phones fully support HTML.  You should consider building your mobile site in regular HTML, but build it in a one column layout (often suggested with mobile UI design -- e.g. scroll up and down, but avoid left and right scrolling).  Make sure your images are reasonably sized, although most phones will scale the content accordingly.

Unless you are targeting a 3rd world country that has old school phone browsers, go with HTML.

Comment: Hey, some of us still have "3rd world phones".  The old standard was called WAP, but as @dolan noted, new smart phones are fully capable browsers.  May I also add refrain from Flash or if you do use flash make sure you detect support and degrade accordingly.

Comment: @Yzmir, you must forgive my narrow-minded iphone-sporting self :p  I look back on my days of having a non-html-supporting browser and shudder (mainly due to developer folk like me never supporting WAP,etc)

Answer (score 1):

Some Use-full link for You::
http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/
http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/designing-for-mobile-web
http://www.drostdesigns.com/mobile-web-design-7-ways-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Answer (score 0):

The browser (mobile or desktop) doesn't care what the server language that is used to server the page is. When designing for mobile, you have to keep in mind the small screen sizes and the sometimes limited browser capabilities.

So your CSS and your markup needs to fit the most common denominator you are aiming for. Just keep it simple.

Have a look at this for more info : http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/designing-for-mobile-web

Answer (score 0):

For cross-browser experience take care about you [X]HTML, CSS, javascript. Doesn't matter what server side language you've used.